# The screen resolution in the application at React Native in Expo does not match the screen resolution of the phone

Tags: react-native, screen, expo, resolution

The screen resolution of the phone is 1920x1080, the screen resolution in the application is 640x360.  How to fix it?  Or should it be?  The application is launched through Expo.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Have a look at the [ask] link and try to add more additional information. What have you investigated so far for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of devices that have unique resolution. Usually i pick some number of the most popular devices and check my app there.
You should write flexible code that will look great on most part of devices. Use flexbox and adaptive design my friend!

Comment: just some addition, if your native resolution is 1920x1080 and the apps resolution is 640x360, you have phone with Pixel Density **3.0**

**(640*3) x (360*3)** equal **1920x1080**

you can styling based on pixel density.

take a look at 
[React Native Pixel Ratio Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio#getfontscale) and 
[material.io](https://material.io/tools/devices/)

and as mentioned by Max, you can use percentage if possible, then move to flexbox, and use pixel as last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions in React Native are measured in density-independent pixels (dp) rather than pixels (px). This allows the user to see it at the same size regardless of the device resolution. So, while your phone is 1920x1080 in px, it is 640x360 in dp.